# How do I force 'Software Updater' and/or 'Software & Updates' to follow Settings - OR - How do I disable/uninstall them?

Tags: gnome, updates, 22.04, update-manager

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It was upgraded "in place" from 20.04. I also have the Gnome desktop installed. There are also two programs installed for "upgrade-by-GUI": `Software Updater` and `Software & Updates`.

Other than the annoyance of having two GUI-updaters (which I guess do exactly the same thing), my primary issue is that I get notifications (pop-up windows) far more frequently than the schedule I have setup in the configuration screen. I despise this behavior, and would like to be shed of it. Here's the config panel for `Software & Updates`; the config panel for `Software Updater` has the same schedule:

[image: Screenshot-Software&Updates]

Apparently the authors of this program have a different perception of "Every two weeks" than I do. What I want is not to hear or see any notifications at all from this annoying application for two weeks after I applied the last update. Is this possible - and if so - what settings must I make?

I would also like to know how to un-install both of these apps... can I do that with `apt`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: does https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux answer your question?

Comment: @24601: It wasn't my intent to disable the updates; I actually don't mind the occasional reminder. But as I said, the GUI doesn't behave IAW the settings I've made (every two weeks). It might be interesting to see if it follows user input for "Never" as well as it does for every two weeks  :)  lol  I'd still like to un-install both of them; the command line does as it's instructed, but GUI apps on Ubuntu have a mind of their own.